# Not able to use tooltip with syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tooltip and syntax highlighter is working on its own, but when I put the code that I want to highlight in the pre tags. Only the syntax highlighting works and tooltip does not.
I tried both [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) [js.Highlighter](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/) .Tooltip still does not work. I am using the tooltip from [simpletooltip](http://www.javascriptf1.com/product/javascript-tooltip.html)
Can anybody guide me as to what to do? Should I change the tooltip or should I change the syntax highlighting. Which tooltip or syntax highlighting should I use?

```
<pre><code class = "python"> 
<p id = "filecontents" class="word_split">False None True False go the way False</p>
</code></pre>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".word_split").lettering('words');
$('.word_split').mouseover(function(event) {
var word=event.target.innerHTML;
if (word == "False")
   showToolTip('False','False keyword',event);
$('.word_split').mouseout(function(event) {
var word=event.target.innerHTML;
if (word == "False")
   hideToolTip();
});
});
});
```

I am using the [letteringplugin](http://letteringjs.com/) to detect the words. Each time the mouse hovers over the word False it should a description.

Comment: At least you need to propose some code with this kind of vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different tooltip (Qtip) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a naming conflict. Please read up on `.noConflict()`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ This is because both are using the $ sign. You need to use an alias like jQuery or whatever so one library doesn't conflict with the other. When using libraries a lot this is bound to happen. It's a good idea to become familiar with noConflict vs just switching out the lib.

**EDIT**

A fair amount of code errors and suggested improvements.

First Your `})` for Mouseover was at the end of the code block instead of at the end of the mouseover. Basically your mouse out was inside your mourseover.

Second when you split the words you create child `span` tags so your selector for mouseover needs to check those.

Third your if statements didn't have `{}`. This means if you ever went more than 1 line of code in your if, it would break (not wrong just not best practice).

Forth since you're using Jquery why not get the word using `$(this)`?

Lastly when comparing strings you may not know if it will be "false" or "False" and case matters so covert both to lowercase and compare for best results unless you are on purposely only wanting False.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#demo2 h1").lettering('words');

    $('.word_split span').mouseover(function(event) {
        var word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (word == "False".toLowerCase()){
           showToolTip('False','False keyword',event);
        }
    });
    $('.word_split span').mouseout(function(event) {
      var word=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (word == "False".toLowerCase()){
         hideToolTip();
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helped me to improve the tooltip. However the tooltip still does not work with js.Highlighter from http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/)

Comment: That wasn't listed in your demo code. Stack Overflow is here to help and point you in the right direction but it's not to do all the work for you. You have working code about. Use firefox/firebug or something to finish debugginh